# Accessing bearer token in java using post API

Tags: java, rest, access-token, spring-security-oauth2, bearer-token

I have to call a `url` to get access token to call subsequent APIs. This token end point is secured with `basic authentication`.

```
token endpoint:- https://xxxxxx.identity.c9dev2.oc9qadev.com/oauth2/v1/token
      username: "xxx-ccc"
      password: "avcdada"
      grant_type: client_credentials
      scope: https://xxxxxx.digitalassistant.oci.oc-test.com/api/v1
      request type: POST
```

I am not able to consume above in java. i tried many codes but none of them working. Can you please, please help me with some link. I am new to `java` and struggling a lot. Below is the code which I used. Its not working.

```
package postapicall;

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Base64;

public class PostApi1 {
    
     public static void main(String []args)
     {
         
    
    try
    {
        String authorization = "";
        String url= "https://idcs-82972921e42641b1bf08128c3d93a19c.identity.c9dev2.oc9qadev.com/oauth2/v1/token";
        String username = "idcs-oda-9417f93560b94eb8a2e2a4c9aac9a3ff-t0_APPID";
        String password = "244ae8e2-6f71-4af2-b5cc-9110890d1456";
        URL address = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection hc = (HttpURLConnection) address.openConnection();

        hc.setDoOutput(true);
        hc.setDoInput(true);
        hc.setUseCaches(false);

        if (username != null && password != null) {
            authorization = username + ":" + password;
        }

        if (authorization != null) {
            byte[] encodedBytes;
            encodedBytes = Base64.encode(authorization.getBytes(), 0);
            authorization = "Basic " + encodedBytes;
            hc.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authorization);
        }

   }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I don't know how the line `encodedBytes = Base64.encode(authorization.getBytes(), 0);` compiles on your machine (there is no `Base64#encode` method).

Assuming your using Java 1.8+, changing:

```java
byte[] encodedBytes;
encodedBytes = Base64.encode(authorization.getBytes(), 0);
authorization = "Basic " + encodedBytes;
hc.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authorization)
```

to

```java
String encodedCredentials = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(authorization.getBytes());
hc.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedCredentials);
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you @Cedric its getting compiled now. Can you tell me how can I use scope ,content-type etc to get token from token endpoint. That code was not complete as I am new.

Comment: Depends on how the endpoint wants to receive it. `grant_type` and `scope` might be required in the message header or as query parameters (`<url>?scope=xxx&grant_type=xxx`).